A newbie question about determining footprint hole diameters
I want to solder a PCB relay socket to a custom PCB which I'm planning to make because I couldn't find any ready footprint. Here is the link to the data sheet.
And below is the exact model:

I will use KiCad. How can the reasonable hole diameters for the footprint pins be determined for the above PCB socket?

You cutoff the descriptions of the drawings. The right drawing is the recommended PCB layout. Holes should be 1.5 mm diameter.

Mattman has the correct answer, the recommended diameter is 1.5mm, however note that manufacturers often pick hole sizes that seem excessively loose for hand assembly, particularly for rectangular or square pins.
That kind of socket has rectangular 1.2 x 0.4 pins that are loose-ish within the molding. You could probably go to 1.4mm or even 1.3mm and get a nicer fit for hand assembly. The pin will fit within a 1.26mm circle, and the edges can shave off a bit of the holes if necessary due to tolerances.
You could also use 0.5 x 1.5mm drilled slots for a really nice fit. Usually that's no extra cost these days. Probably what I would do:

Don't play these games too much with solidly mounted round pins though, there is nowhere for excess and pin location tolerances to go and you might have to spin a new board since you can't drill out plated-through holes without ruining them.
Also, if you're calling it close, confirm that the fab you are using will take your dimensions as finished hole sizes, not drill sizes. Most do, but I've run into a few that expect you to make the adjustments to drill sizes.

Another caveat: As this is a socket, this almost surely doesn't apply here, but if you use larger holes than necessary, it makes it much easier to desolder parts, if you intend to repeatedly solder and remove parts from a board (e.g. a test fixture for very high-current or RF devices, where a socket would be too impractical).

I think "excessively loose" is not the main problem. The amount of solder you have to pour in there is. Not for 1.5 mm pins though. But for parts like these custom holes pretty much a must, regardless of what datasheet says
